# What am I doing thats causing Unknown Provider when Adding both a service and a filter or multiple services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is most likely due to my lack of experience and overlooking something fundamental but between SO, the angulajs [tutorials](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)  and [guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide) as well as Googling and I can't find an explaination or example that I can follow.

I have successfully created a factory and used it in my controller and a filter but Only one or the other. when I try to add both to the module I get `Error: Unknown provider: memberFactoryProvider <- memberFactory`

my code is below but some questions I have include:

**1.** When adding the factory and service (or multiple factories/filters) to a module is it enough to create them the same way as you with a single factory i.e.
if I have a number of factories delclared like so:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('testApp', [])
    .factory('factory1', function () {
        var obj = {};
        obj.text = "This is a test";
        return obj;
    });
angular.module('testApp', [])
    .factory('factory2', function () {
        var obj = {};
        obj.text = "This is another test";
        return obj;
    });
```

is it enough to inlcude the two in app.js using `angular.module('testApp', ['factory1', 'factory2']);`

**2.** I have noticed some posts online that when creating a filter/factory they append the appname e.g.:

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
          .factory('testApp.factory1', function () {
          var obj = {};

          obj.text = "This is a test";
      return obj;});
```

is this required or personal preference?

Finally below is all my code, as mentioned above, all work indiviually but when I try to combine them I get the error mentioned above, any advice or help is greatly appreciated

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="testApp">

    <head>
        <title>prototype</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-ng-controller="myController">
            <br/>
            <div data-ng-repeat="n in [] | range:5">
                <div data-ng-repeat="">{{test}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/filters.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

App.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('testApp', ['memberFactory', 'range']);
```

services.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('testApp',[])
    .factory('memberFactory', function(){
        var obj = {};

        obj.text = "This is a test";
        return obj;
    });
```

filters.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('testApp',[]).filter('testApp.range', function() {
  return function(input, total) {
    total = parseInt(total);
    for (var i=0; i<total; i++)
      input.push(i);
    return input;
  };
});
```

controllers.js

```
function myController($scope, memberFactory){ 
            $scope.test= memberFactory.text;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should be doing this

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
.factory('factory1', function () {
    var obj = {};
    obj.text = "This is a test";
    return obj;
})

.factory('factory2', function () {
    var obj = {};
    obj.text = "This is another test";
    return obj;
});
```

---

You shouldn't create 2 modules of the same name.

And I think that this

```
angular.module('something', ['here', 'is', 'for modules', 'only'];
```

I think what you are trying to do is this.

You have 2 modules?

```
var helpers = angular.module('helpers', []);
```

Then you should do

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['helpers']);
```

Then you will have access to all factories that are attached to helpers and app

Say for example you want your filters in another file there are a few ways to do it

```
var filters = angular.module('filters', []);
filters.filter('name', func...);
```

Then you include it in your app like so

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['helpers', 'filters']);
```

Comment: Ok but if for argument sake, say it was a filter and a service what then? Would it be module().filter().factory()? If so how would this work if filters in one file and factory in another?

Comment: I have added a example in my answer or you could do `window.app = angular.module.....` then use app.filter in another file.